# GUI programming with scala: what are the libraries and tools I can use?

Tags: scala, user-interface

I never did GUI stuff in java or scala. I experimented a little bit with C# and visual studio in the past and there was this visual gui builder, where I could just drag and drop elements.

Does something like this exist in scala?

I read something about javaFX and I saw the [SceneBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/release-documentation.html). Alternatively I could just use java for GUI programming right?

Comment: The two whales of gui programming on jvm are swing and javaFX (well, there is awt, but it's low level and obsolete and I don't think it is suited for begginers). Both have wrappers ([scala.swing](http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/sids/imaier/Mon,%202009-11-02,%2008:55/scala-swing-design.pdf) as part of official scala distrubution, but in a separate jar and [scalaFX](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/) as a standalone library).

Comment: `scala-swing` is the best place to start. It's bundled with the SDK along with some good examples. You can also write JavaFX using Scala, which is more powerful than Swing, but will be a bit trickier to get started with. ScalaFX is a project that wraps JavaFX with better syntax, but it's not ready yet and is more or less undocumented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [xscalaawt](https://github.com/nafg/ScalaSWT)
- [scalaFX](http://code.google.com/p/scalafx/)

Also see [gsl-swt](https://github.com/mikegr/gsl-swt/wiki)